# MVC: How to display a modal popup after calling the ActionResult

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to display a modal popup once a button is pushed, I made it with JS, but the issue that the popup is displayed before the ActionResult is executed, so I had many bugs.
If I remove the JS function from the button, the page is displayed correctly, but not a popup. A full `.cshtml` vue.

Here is the JS part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#submitupload').click(function () {
    window.open('@Url.Action("Result", "Home")', "uploadFormSuccess", 
    "height=600,width=600,modal=yes,alwaysRaised=yes");

   });
</script>
```

Here is the `ActionResult` in the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult Result()
{
    try
    {
        return PartialView("uploadFormSuccess");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error(ex.Message);
        return PartialView("Error");
    }
}
```

Does anybody know how to "oblige" the  action of the button to go to controller first and display a modal popup?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Ajax to send the request, and after the upload finished, popup your dialog.

Comment: $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: ' ',
            data:  
            },
            success: function (data) {
                
                var successAlert = $('#sucess-alert');

                successAlert.show();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    successAlert.fadeToggle(fadeDuration);
                }, fadeDelay);
            }
        });
What should I do put in the url and data ?

Comment: The URL should be your controller's URL-pattern.
Depends on your framework, it's different.
Raw web applications uses web.xml to configure servlets and their URL-pattern. Spring and other frameworks have different configuration.

Comment: And data should be the values you want to send to your controller. Should be in JSON format